# Sum a particular column and take the unique record of another using AWK only

Tags: unix, awk

I have an input file like the following:

```
19 | 17 | 1 | 89 | C | 9 | 100 | 9 | PL | 2175
20 | 17 | 1 | 89 | C | 9 | 100 | 9 | PL | 2175
21 | 17 | 2 | 89 | C | 9 | 100 | 9 | PL | 2175
23 | 17 | 2 | 89 | C | 9 | 100 | 9 | PL | 2175
24 | 17 | 1 | 89 | C | 9 | 100 | 9 | PL | 2175
27 | 17 | 1 | 89 | C | 9 | 100 | 9 | PL | 2175
```

I want to sum the column value of 6 alone, and in 4th, 5th, 9th, and 10th columns, I want to remove the duplicate and print a single value as `PL` and `2175`.

> `19 | 17 | 1 |`
>   *{remove duplicate and single value}* `|`
>   *{remove duplicate and single value}* `|`
>   *{sum here}* `|`*{sum here}* `|` *{sum here}* `|`
>   *{remove duplicate*} `|` *{remove duplicate}*

I tried the following:

> `grep 0000000089181` *input file* `| awk -F'|' '
>
>           { sum_p_all += $5} ;
>
>           { sum_quantity += $6} ;
>
>           { mean_p_unit = sum_p_all/sum_quantity} ;
>
>           { sum_p_all2 = sum_p_all * 100} ;
>
>           { mean_p_unit2 = mean_p_unit * 100}
>
>   END     { print sum_p_all2 " " sum_quantity " " mean_p_unit2 }'`

Comment: Assuming your columns are separated by "|", this can easily be done; but I find it hard to match your goal description to your data: col 6 is not numeric; you also add up col 5, then divide for some mean; and I don't see how your goals produce the 3 col + |'es output at end. Could you try to explain again?

Comment: My bad: 6 is numeric, but 5 which you sum too isn't.

Comment: So what do you want to sum? Only the numeric part of 6? Only the `14,5`? Please [edit] your question and include _actual_ example output. Also, what is the sum you want in each column? The sum of that column over the entire file?

Comment: ***Please*** clarify your question.  For example, you say, “I want to sum the column value of 6 alone”, but you show summing columns 7 and 8 also.  For another example, ***every*** value in column 1 begins with `0111`, ***every*** value in column 2 is `1774`, ***every*** value in column 3 begins with `0000000`, and so on.   This makes it very difficult for a person to look at the values and see which ones are the same and which ones are different.  I tried to remove the unnecessary duplication, leaving only essential data.  Please verify that I didn’t damage the question.

Comment: Hi gnometorule/terdon/scott- Thanks so much for your quick responses.
I tried yesterday and got the answer as expected.. pAsting the answer below

Answer (score 0):

What precisely you want, is till unclear to me; but the following code addresses something along the lines of what you seem to have in mind. It sums all values; and only keeps (prints) records which are unique with respect to all of cols 4, 5, 9, and 10, in which case we keep the first such record seen. The cols are printed 1, 2, 3, 9, 10, 6, 7, 8. Maybe you can adjust this to precisely what you want, or provide further info. The p/o is unsorted; if you want it sorted by, say, col 1, just pipe the output into sort.

```
#!/usr/bin/awk - f
# or your system's location
BEGIN{
   FS=OFS="|";
   s6=s7=s8=0;
   t="";
   a[""]="";
   seen[""]=0;
}

{
   s6 += $6;
   s7 += $7;
   s8 += $8;

   t = $4 $5 $9 $10;
   seen[t]++;
   if (seen[t] == 1)
      a[t] = $1 "|" $2 "|" $3 "|" $9 "|" $10 "|" $6 "|" $7 "|" $8;
}

END{
   for (i in a)
      print a[i];
   print s6, s7, s8;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

i just tried using uniq inside awk and it worked.

awk -F'|' '{ column4 = uniq $4 } ; {coumn5 = uniq $5 }; { coumn6 += $6} ; {column7 += $7} ; {column8 += $8}; {column9 = uniq $9} ; {coulmn10 = uniq $10 } END { print column4 "|"  column5  "|" column6  "|" column7 "|"  column8  "|" column9 "|" column10}'